# Bootstrap row glitch with text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see from the attached example, if the first column has more text than the one to it's right, then it causes a glitch. See the screenshot attached.

How do I resolve this in Bootstrap?

[image]

**Demo:**
 https://jsfiddle.net/oLderkuo/

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    
    <div class="portfolio-gallery row">

  <div class='gallery-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
   <span class='sub-gallery-icon'>
    <a href='#' >
     <img width="300" height="200" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="gallery-thumb-img wp-post-image" alt="" />
    </a>
   </span>
   <span class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'><br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. 
   </span>
  </div>

  <div class='gallery-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
   <span class='sub-gallery-icon'>
    <a href='#' >
     <img width="300" height="200" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="gallery-thumb-img wp-post-image" alt="" />
    </a>
   </span>
   <span class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'><br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
   </span>
  </div>

  <div class='gallery-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
   <span class='sub-gallery-icon'>
    <a href='#' >
     <img width="300" height="200" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="gallery-thumb-img wp-post-image" alt="" />
    </a>
   </span>
   <span class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'><br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. 
   </span>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try :text-align: justify; ? In your css ?

Comment: @NathanSchwarz I have tried here: https://jsfiddle.net/oLderkuo/1/ but I don't think this will resolve the issue.

Comment: OK so first of all its very important to put bootdtrap classes first and to order by width properity : XS - MD - LG

Comment: @NathanSchwarz what? the order doesn't matter. The order matters in the css file declaration but not on the element..

Comment: @user3528269 Yep, you're right :-( https://jsfiddle.net/oLderkuo/2/

Comment: @user3528269 Do you think I should just reduce the amount of text or is there a fix in the CSS I can do?

Comment: @user3528269 yes the order matters if there is a conflict between 2 properities of 2 classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a found a solution via https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9454

I have updated my Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/oLderkuo/3/

Basically after every 2nd `gallery item` div I have to add the following:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is that Bootstrap applies a float to the col-* classes - meaning that your divs are not displaying correctly - rather than adding unnecessary divs to the markup just to clear the float - solve the problem.

This code will iterate through each of the divs , determine its height and if it is great than the max-height will adjust the max height. Then it will apply the max height to all the divs and the problem will be resolved.

Note that I have added a resize function to this, and aconsole .log to demonstrate the max height, but the vagaries of the snipp editor do not allow the best environment to see this in action - try copying it out to your own page and try it in the wild. It really does work.

```js
adjustHeight();
$( window ).resize(function() {
   adjustHeight();
});



function adjustHeight(){
    var maxHeight=0;
    $('.gallery-item').each(function(){
    var height=$(this).height();
    if(height> maxHeight){maxHeight=height};
      console.log(maxHeight);
    });

    $('.gallery-item').css('height',maxHeight+'px');
  }
```

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="portfolio-gallery row">

  <div class='gallery-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
   <span class='sub-gallery-icon'>
    <a href='#' >
     <img width="300" height="200" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="gallery-thumb-img wp-post-image" alt="" />
    </a>
   </span>
   <span class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'><br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. 
   </span>
  </div>

  <div class='gallery-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
   <span class='sub-gallery-icon'>
    <a href='#' >
     <img width="300" height="200" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="gallery-thumb-img wp-post-image" alt="" />
    </a>
   </span>
   <span class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'><br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
   </span>
  </div>

  <div class='gallery-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
   <span class='sub-gallery-icon'>
    <a href='#' >
     <img width="300" height="200" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="gallery-thumb-img wp-post-image" alt="" />
    </a>
   </span>
   <span class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'><br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. 
   </span>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review my issue. When I try this, I get the following: http://imgur.com/a/WpHU3

Comment: Hi - yes thats why I just added the resize function so that when you move between different vieport sizes it will adjust. That is happening because the initial time the function runs it is setting the divs at 340px and then doesn't recalculate. Try it with the resize function.

Comment: Unfortunately it only starts to work when I resize the viewport. On load it doesn't display properly. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Fixed now - wrapped it in a document.ready ;-) You're a LEGEND!!

Comment: no worries - sorry I didn't include a doc ready cos I thought you would have already had one. I have used this - or a version of it on a number of projects that required the heights to be as tall as the tallest element. Makes it very cruisy! Happy Coding.

Comment: Haha - I'll bet it does. Yep, I did have one just totally forgot to use it. Made my day. Thank you @gavgrif :-D

Comment: One more thing before I forget - would proabably suggest to add a magin bottom to the div ()or add an offset to the maxHeight) so that when the divs do collapse down - there is some space between the bottom of one and the top of the other.

Comment: That's a really valid point - will add that in just now and do further testing. Thank you :)